# Downloaded python3.5 from source, but pip3 does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, installation, pip

I've downloaded python3 from source, expecting it to come with pip3 but instead, it defaults to pip from version 2.7 even though my python is 3.5.1.
(I found similar posts to this question but none had a concrete solution besides using a venv, which I don't want to do)

The commands I use to get to this point are:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar zxvf Python-3.5.1.tgz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3 --with-sqlite --with-ensurepip=install
make
sudo make install
```

It's worth noting that I'm working on a clean aws instance that has `sqlite-devel`, `gcc`,  and `openssl-devel` in it.

Is there an efficient way for me to get pip3 alongside python3?

Comment: Are you sure pip is missing? Try `cd`ing to the `bin` directory of the Python installation and look for files called `pip`, `pip3` or `pip3.5` (they are all really the same).

Comment: What is the result of `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: @jmd_dk, the bin directory only contains `pip2.7`. And every time I do `--version` I only get 2.7 as a response.

Comment: @minhhn2910 the result of `$PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin`

Comment: The `/opt/python3/bin` directory contains `pip2.7`? That seems very strange indeed. Are you sure that you are looking in the correct directory, where you installed Python *3*?

Comment: @jmd_dk, I'm mistaken! sorry I followed the wrong path, I do see pip in `/home/ec2-user/Python-3.5.1/Tools/msi/pip`

Comment: @LaughingHorse OK, but according to your code you installed it into `/opt/python3`?

Comment: How about the result of : `sudo /opt/python3/bin/python3.5 -m ensurepip` ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure this one out so I nuked my instance and redid all the steps from above on a fresh instance and found pip3 this time around in `/opt/python3/bin`.

What's strange/ I don't understand, is why I can't search for this executable with `find`. Also, I calling the `path/to/pip3` is the only way to get it to work, but that's okay. It's working now at least.

Thank you very much for the suggestions posted in the comments above!